# Vertical alignment in command \author

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, author

How to align the names and numbers inside the command `\autor`?

```
 \title{MWE align author}
  \documentclass[
      12pt,
      openright,ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
      twoside,
      a4paper,
      english,
      french,   
      spanish,
      brazil,   
      ]{abntex2}


  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{indentfirst}  
  \usepackage{color}            
  \usepackage{graphicx}     
  \usepackage{microtype}        
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{lipsum}   
  \usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}   
  \usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite} 
  \usepackage{titling} 
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{array}


  \renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
  \renewcommand{\backref}{}
  \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
      \ifcase #1 %
          Nenhuma citação no texto.%
      \or
          Citado na página #2.%
      \else
          Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
      \fi}%
  \titulo{Modelo Canônico de\\ Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico com \abnTeX}

  \autor{Name One \qquad number1 \\
          Other Name \qquad number2}

  \local{São Carlos}
  \data{2017}
  \tipotrabalho{Relatório técnico}
  \preambulo{Modelo canônico de Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico em conformidade
  com as normas ABNT apresentado à comunidade de usuários \LaTeX.}

  \definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

  \makeatletter
  \hypersetup{
          pdftitle={\@title}, 
          pdfauthor={\@author},
          pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
          pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
          pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{relatório técnico}, 
          colorlinks=true,  
          linkcolor=blue,   
          citecolor=blue,   
          filecolor=magenta,        urlcolor=blue,
          bookmarksdepth=4
  }
  \makeatother
  \setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

  \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
  \makeindex
  \begin{document}

  \selectlanguage{brazil}

  \frenchspacing 

  \imprimircapa
  \end{document}
```

EDIT:
I wanna make this
[image]

look like this

[image]

Comment: What other need for vertical alignment do you have (the numbers should be just fine)? Do you maybe mean the horizontal alignment? Maybe you could add a picture of what you're trying to change.

Comment: Edited the question, now it should be clear

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright, ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso) twoside, a4paper, english, french, spanish, brazil]{abntex2}
\usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
  \usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
  \usepackage{titling}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

  \renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
  \renewcommand{\backref}{}
  \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
      \ifcase #1 %
          Nenhuma citação no texto.%
      \or
          Citado na página #2.%
      \else
          Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
      \fi}%
  \titulo{Modelo Canônico de\\ Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico com \abnTeX}

  \autor{\eqmakebox[Name][r]{Name One} \qquad \eqmakebox[number][l]{number1} \\
          \eqmakebox[Name][r]{Another Name} \qquad \eqmakebox[number][l]{number2}}

  \local{São Carlos}
  \data{2017}
  \tipotrabalho{Relatório técnico}
  \preambulo{Modelo canônico de Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico em conformidade
  com as normas ABNT apresentado à comunidade de usuários \LaTeX.}

  \definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

  \makeatletter
  \hypersetup{
          pdftitle={\@title},
          pdfauthor={\@author},
          pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
          pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
          pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{relatório técnico},
          colorlinks=true,
          linkcolor=blue,
          citecolor=blue,
          filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=blue,
          bookmarksdepth=4
  }
  \makeatother
  \setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

  \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
  \makeindex

  \begin{document}

  \selectlanguage{brazil}

  \frenchspacing

  \imprimircapa

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (no line number):
Runaway argument?
{\begin {tabular{r@{\qquad }l} Name One & number1 \\ Other Name & num\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \autor.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> main.tex

Comment: @BadWolf: I didn't know your document class, but I've posted another (tested) solution. Please see if it's OK for you.